# http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd can not be read

Tags: jasper-reports

I inserted a HTML element into my japserreporttest.jrxml and the code generated automatically is like this:

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement x="466" y="579" width="100" height="30" uuid="4d62f8bd-23d4-4199-97bb-a703a0769a8c"/>
    <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RetainShape" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Middle">
        <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA["<p style='background-color:yellow;'>HTML paragraph</p>"]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
    </hc:html>
</componentElement>
```

But when I tried to generate the report I get the following error "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd cannot be read". I input this URL in browser and get the 404 error. Do you know what happened with source forge?

Comment: the jasper report website is moved to http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library. But the template hasn't been updated and cannot be modified manually. I gave up to use the html element, instead I am using table element now.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, you should add the library jasperreports-htmlcomponent.

If you are using maven you add :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperreports-htmlcomponent</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Else this is a link to the jar : http://maven.sonner.com.br/~maven2/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports-htmlcomponent/5.0.1/

Comment: this link is broke

Comment: The dependency also is broke. I'm having the same issue.